# How can I exclude the production track from being submitted to Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, code-push, react-native-code-push

I am preparing an app update on Google Play. Our app has two active tracks: open test and production. I already created a release with the update for both tracks. Managed publishing has been turned on, so nothing has been published yet. I should only release to the open test track at this moment. I can't seem to remove the release to production though, so now I'm thinking of creating a new release for production with the same old build as the one which is currently active in production.

However, I wonder what will happen if I release this version. Will Android devices recognise this release as an update and download and install the app again? We also work with CodePush, so I also wonder what will happen with people who have currently downloaded the latest CodePush version. Will they lose it after installing the same build and do they need to download it again?